# How do I fix my CSS menu with rounded image background

Tags: html, css

I want to show the rounded image on the left and right menu. You can see the example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/9DENH/)**. The background image is:

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="current" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Faq</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>    
</ul>
```

Let me know the trick on CSS to achieve my goal without cutting the current image.

---

The result should be like this

[image]

---

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9DENH/6/)** is the final result using `sliding doors technique`

Comment: I don't think you can do it without using advanced stuff from CSS3 -- but I assume you cannot use CSS3 because otherwise you would simply have used border-radius.  To have this sort of thing work in IE, you'll have to use a few div's (one to hold the left, one to hold the right, one to hold the middle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sliding doors technique.
And your main problem is that `<li>`s are floated so `<ul>` has 0 height. You can either float ul also, or give it `overflow:hidden`

http://jsfiddle.net/9DENH/3/

================================

UPDATE:
sorry speed read will kill me one day :)

Here is my updated answer: http://jsfiddle.net/9DENH/5/

Add this to css:

```
li {
padding-left: 10px;/* to create gap that will not be overlapped with <a> background */
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLgZA.png) no-repeat left top #000;

}
li a, li a.current {
background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLgZA.png) no-repeat right top #000;
    text-indent: -10px; /* same as li padding, to realign centered text */
}
```

This is basic you should add hover states.

Comment: I found the solution [CSS Sliding Door using only 1 image](http://kailoon.com/css-sliding-door-using-only-1-image/)

Comment: Last sentence in answer is about that, I'm not here to do a full time job but to provide an example ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `border-radius:5px` and `background: linear-gradient(startcolor, endcolor);`

For IE support use the [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/)

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9DENH/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS rounded corners and it works just fine w/ the background image you have there (although you don't need the image's corners to be rounded and the image doesn't have to be so wide - 10px wide is just find since it repeats-x.

```
li a:link, li a:visited {
     background-image: url('../images/navBg.jpg');
     background-repeat: repeat-x;
     background-position: top left;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    }

li a:hover, li a:active{
    background-position: bottom left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use the images as a sprite?

If so you have to choose diffrent positions on the background,
and you also will have to define a height and width for each element.